# Save response of GET request as class object

Tags: java, get-request

I am trying to fetch some date using a `GET` request towards an API. What I want to do is to save the response of this request as a Java class I have created beforehand. Here´s my class:

```java
import java.util.List;
    
public class Person {
    String name = null;
    List<Siblings> siblings  = null;
}
```

And here´s how I am sending a GET request and reading data as String:

```java
try {
    URL url = new URL("someURL");
    
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + "bearerString");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    InputStream content = (InputStream) connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I save the response of the Http Request in a class object instead of just a String?

Comment: That depends: What is the response format? XML? JSON? Bytes with serialized Java object? CSV text? Something else?

Comment: It´s JSON, @Andreas

Comment: Then use a **JSON parser** library that also support object mapping, e.g. Jackson, Gson, ...

Comment: This answers your question: [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2591098/5221149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Jackson` https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Example:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Person person = mapper.readValue(json, Person.class);
```